# alter add column to temptable from another query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which creates a temporary table `#object` with one column `(id int)`, and I want to extend `#object` with columns from a another query results. I've tried using a cursor:

```
CREATE TABLE #object(ID int)

DECLARE @q int    
DECLARE @getid CURSOR

SET @getid= CURSOR FOR
select Q.Question /*, QR.ResponseText, QR.DynamicQuestionResponseID*/  from     DynamicForms_Question as Q
inner join DynamicForms_QuestionResponse as QR on Q.DynamicQuestionID = QR.DynamicQuestionID 
where Q.ModuleID = 729 
and QR.ResponseDateTime = '2012-12-27 11:31:00'
and QuestionType <> 'Label'
and QuestionType <> 'HR'
order by Q.SortOrder asc

OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @q
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Alter Table #object add -- what can i use here????
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @q
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid

drop table #object
```

Comment: You'll have to get into dynamic SQL and create the DDL on the fly. But, what is the root issue you're trying to solve? (This smells a little bit like an XY problem.)

Comment: I want instead of vertical horizontal data: results of column Table1.Question as columns for temptable, and result column Table2.Response as values ​for temptable.